# C++ sector aligned read

Tags: c++, windows, readfile

Im asking this because i am having trouble understanding sector aligned reading when we are reading raw device.

Lets assume whe are in a Windows machined, and we are using the `ReadFile()` C function to read x bytes from a device.

I know we can only read sector aligned data, but recently i discovered the `SetFilePointer()` function, that allow us to put a pointer in x bytes of the device we have previously opened with `CreateFile()`.

My question is, if we need to read sector aligned data, if we use `SetFilePointer()` for example like this:

```
SetFilePointer(device, 12, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
```

(device is a `HANDLE` to an existing device,for the sake of this example lets assume its a USB pen drive), in that example we set a pointer thatis pointing to the 12th byte starting from `FILE_BEGIN`.

If i were to read the equivalent of one sector (512 bytes) starting from that 12th byte, would i need to make my read fucntion like this:

```
ReadFile(device, sector, (512 - 12), &bytesRead, NULL)
```

or like this:

```
ReadFile(device, sector, 512, &bytesRead, NULL)
```

Regardless, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, if we need to read sector aligned data, if we use `SetFilePointer()` for example like this:
>
> ```
> SetFilePointer(device, 12, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
> ```

... then you are no longer reading sector-aligned data, and you'll get error 87 in the `ReadFile` call. Reading sector-aligned data doesn't just mean that you have to read in sector-sized blocks, but you must always read blocks that start on sector boundaries.

You have to seek to the sector containing the bytes of your interest (so, `position/sector_size*sector_size`), read the whole sector and extract the bytes of your interest from the data you read.

Comment: so i can use `SetFilePointer()` to point to whatever, but i cant use `ReadFile()` if the `SetFilePointer()` isnt pointing to the beginning of a sector?

Comment: Yes; in general, it doesn't make sense to seek to unaligned positions if you are working on raw devices.

Comment: @MatteoItalia i tried this in a project and if i, for example, put the `SetFilePointer()` in 40 for example, and use `ReadFile()` for 512 bytes, it works, why is that? shouldnt it give me a error because im reading out of sector order?

Comment: It depends from whatever the driver or device feels like doing, but ***it's not supported***, as explained in the link in my previous answer. It may happen to work, but it's just luck, change device or Windows version or driver or whatever and it won't work anymore. Play by the rules and you won't have problems.

Comment: @jeyejow: are you the same user as drk?

Comment: @MatteoItalia no, i just found the question and decided to try what drk was asking

Comment: @MatteoItalia so i always have to do `floor(position/512) * 512` and put the pointer there? that is the correct way?

Comment: Yes (although there's no need to explicitly floor - integer division already does the right thing).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends..

- if you want what's in your buffer to represent an entire sector of the device, and map it using a struct* or byte offsets - that's usually how it's done.  then your offsets sent to SetFilePointer should be aligned on the sector size, then read sector sized buffers. So SetFilePointer(0) -> ReadFile(512 bytes)
- If you don't care, and just want bytes 12-16, SetFilePointer(12) -> Read(4bytes).

I'd go for solution 1, because it would probably make the code easier to read and maintain in the long run.

Comment: but you can only use the `ReadFile()` and read bytes that are sector alligned, for example 512, 1024, and so on, at a time

Comment: Then, unaligned SetFilePointers() should fail as well.